# What's wrong with this Elastic query

Tags: elasticsearch

Why this query works fine (returns the proper result):

```
{
  "filter": {
    "term": { "id": "123456" }
  }
}
```

and this one does not (returns HTTP 500):

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
      "term": { "id": "123456" }
    }
  }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch expects query element on the root level similar to the "filter" element. Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": { "id": "123456" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This one works too. Thanks! Will accept your answer in 6 minutes :)